# How to create a listview with the undetermined numbers of elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, disassembly

How can I create a listview with the undetermined(or variable)numbers of elements?

I am developing a disassembler which supports x86, arm, etc. It shows the disassembly in a listview. It correctly supports static analysis. But I want to add a "jump to any address" feature for x86 architecture.

When showing RISC arch's disassembly in listview, the number of elements are quite measurable and fixed as its instructuons have a fixed size(4 bytes each).

In case of RISC architectures like ARM, the disassembly usually doesn't change even if the program jumps. However in case of CISC architectures like x86, when the program jumps inside an instruction, the total disassembly changes. And of course does the number of instructions(==number of elements of listview) too!

I tried to implement something like a table of index, and use fixed size(300) of listview.

```
DisasmResult[] disasmTable;
int [] indexofTable;//position->index table. Pre generate it when user jumps or scrolls the listview to the bottom.
public View getView(position)
{  
    return createView(disasmTable[indexofTable[position]]);
}
```

**Detailed explanations(finding a better examples)**

```
void confuseReverser()
{
    _asm{
        mov eax, 0
        cmp eax, 0
        je gogo
       emit 0xeb
    gogo:
       ...
}
```

Comment: Seems like this question is te oppertunity to get out of the question ban. I'll put every effort of mine yo be well received!!!

Comment: You may be confused, but we are even more confused. Please explain with more detail, and less story.

Comment: @lionscribe Yep! Thank you!!!

Comment: You will have to post more code. What is `disasmTable`?

Comment: @lionscribe i'll post it too. I'll let you know when I finish writing.

Comment: I still haven't figured out the issue, but I can tell you, that you will have much better options and memory usage, if you switch to a RecyclerView, rather then a ListView.

Comment: @lionscribe Thanks to your help, I found out another way to try. I'll ask again when I encounter a problem there. Thanks for your help!!